# Is the morphism of affine varieties given by Noether Normalisation a closed map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb A^n(k)$ be an affine variety over the algebraically closed field $k$. Then by the geometric interpretation of Noether Normalisation Lemma there is a finite and surjective morphism $\varphi:X\to \mathbb A^m(k)$, where $m$ is the dimension of $X$ (see here for the process [noether normalization theorem geometric meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320309/noether-normalization-theorem-geometric-meaning?rq=1)).

Is it true that the morphism $\varphi:X\to \mathbb A^m(k)$ is a closed map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any finite morphism is proper (hence universally closed).

Comment: But the O.P. spoke of a finite morphism (Normalisation lemma is about a morphism being finite).

Comment: @Bernard I didn't know that fact. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.